# Filtering a nested PySpark DataFrame based on the internal fields

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame whose sample element is (obtained with a take(1)):

```
[Row(id=u'1', objects=Row('a'=Row(fav=True, ratio=0.5), 'b'=Row(fav=False, ratio=0.0))]
```

that is, the structure is composite so that the column *objects* is an array of Rows (which are then composite as well as they contain two fields).

How would I filter based on the nested elements, namely on the content of objects? Say I want to search, for the row whose id is '1', which is the ratio on the object called 'b', for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> df = sc.parallelize([Row(id=u'1', objects=Row(a=Row(fav=True, ratio=0.5), b=Row(fav=False, ratio=0.0)))]).toDF()
>>> df.where("id = 1").select("objects.a.ratio").show()
+-----+
|ratio|
+-----+
|  0.5|
+-----+
```